# How to efficiently store Large JSON file containing geospatial data

Tags: sql-server, json, mongodb, azure

My application stores geospatial data of a journey of a vehicle in SQL database. The geospatial data is latitude and longitude values of the vehicle every five seconds. The JourneyData table looks something like below:

```
For Journey Id = 1; GeoSpatial Data is [[40.1,50.2],[40.2,50.3].......[60.1,70.1]]

For Journey Id = 2; GeoSpatial Data is [[40.1,50.2],[40.2,50.3].......[50.1,60.1]]
```

Here `Journey Id` is `int` and `GeoSpatial Data` is `ntext`.

The geospatial data is huge. e.g. the largest geospatial data is for a 5 day journey, where there are `5*24hrs*60min*60sec/5sec = 86400` coordinates. When i tried to store geospatial data array for 5 day journey in mongodb, the document size was around 40MB.

MongoDB has a document size restriction of `16MB`. Hence I used gridfs provided by MongoDB, to store the data in a file. I am not sure if this is the best solution.

There are 2 million journey records. The size of current geospatial data ranges from few KBs to `40MB` depending on length of jouney. The size of JourneyData  SQL table is around `40GB`. I need to transform, store and retrieve this data efficiently to another database and then bind it in google maps to show the journey route. My application is hosted on azure. Please let me know best possible ways to accomplish this.

Should I use mongodb or azure blob or anything else?

Comment: This sounds like you should just filter the data, with every SELECT request.  So, at any time (like after every pan/zoom change), you make a query (You do this with an Ajax call.) that selects only the markers within the lat/lng bounds of the map.   Then you can cluster the markers, with SQL.  You make a grid of your map (like 10 * 10 sqares), and with a GROUP BY you show the numer of markers in that grid cel.  If you're interested, I can search my answer to a similar problem.  Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing it as the geography data type? I just ran the following test generating (admittedly fake) data and storing it as a linestring. It came out to under 1.5 Mb

```
DECLARE @g GEOGRAPHY, @gt VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @gt = 'LINESTRING(' + 
STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + CAST(40 + n * 0.0001 AS varchar(15)) + ' ' + CAST(40 + n * 0.0001 AS varchar(10))
    FROM [dbo].[Numbers] AS [n]
    WHERE n <= 86400
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') + ')';

SELECT @g = GEOGRAPHY::STLineFromText(@gt, 4236)
SELECT DATALENGTH(@g);
```